# Powershell Import-PfxCertificate prompts for location despite parameters

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, pfx

I am trying to import a certificate on a VM.
I am doing the following script:

```
Start-VM -Name $NewVmName
Copy-VMFile -Name $NewVmName -SourcePath ".\certificate.pfx"  -DestinationPath "C:\certificate.pfx" -CreateFullPath -FileSource Host

$Password = "test" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
Invoke-Command -VMName $NewVmName -Credential $LocalCredential -ScriptBlock {       
    Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "C:\certificate.pfx" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $Password
}
```

So the certificate store location is indicated. However, when I run this script, Windows prompts me to know in which store I want to import the certificate:

[image]

How come? what do I do wrong? I want the certificate to be imported without any user interactions of course.

Thanks!

Comment: Read about `ScriptBlock` in `Get-Help Invoke-Command  -Online`: _By default, any variables in the command are evaluated on the remote computer. To include local variables in the command, use `ArgumentList`_. I can see the `$Password` local variable…

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it does not change the fact that I have the same prompt dialog.